# Simplifying my stored procedure (cte, merge)

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, merge, common-table-expression

I have pieced together a rather long, possibly inefficient stored procedure.  The sproc receives a JSON of SKUs, along with some parameters, in order to bulk update two different tables with the same set of data.  The data itself comes from the first table (ProductValidation) so those will always be UPDATE, but the second table may or may not have any of these records available.  (I just left both cases as a merge UPDATE or INSERT, even though the first case will always be an UPDATE - but I don't think this detracts much from performance...).

Please let me know if you see any where I could make this better?  I'm somewhat novice so looking to you pros, thanks!

```sql
WITH cte AS (

    SELECT
        SellingSkuCode AS SellingSkuCodez
    FROM
        OPENJSON( @json ) WITH (
            SellingSkuCode                varchar(100),
            MaterialDescription           varchar(8000),
            TranslatedMaterialDescription varchar(8000),
            LocalErpSubbrand              varchar(8000),
            HarmonizedSubbrand            varchar(500),
            GrossRevenue                  varchar(100),
            Priority                      varchar(100),
            Validated                     varchar(100),
            MarketUnitName                varchar(100),
            UpdatedBy                     varchar(100)
        )
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        cte
        INNER JOIN ProductValidation B ON cte.SellingSkuCodez = B.SellingSkuCode
)
MERGE ProductValidation original
USING cte2 modified ON (
    original.SellingSkuCode = modified.SellingSkuCode
    AND
    original.MarketUnitName = @Market
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET

    original.SellingSkuCode                = modified.SellingSkuCode,
    original.MaterialDescription           = modified.MaterialDescription,
    original.TranslatedMaterialDescription = modified.TranslatedMaterialDescription,
    original.LocalErpSubbrand              = modified.LocalErpSubbrand,
    original.HarmonizedSubbrand            = @HarmonizedSubbrand,
    original.GrossRevenue                  = modified.GrossRevenue,
    original.Priority                      = modified.Priority,
    original.Validated                     = modified.Validated,
    original.MarketUnitName                = @Market,
    original.UpdatedBy                     = @UpdatedBy

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (
        SellingSkuCode,
        MaterialDescription,
        TranslatedMaterialDescription,
        LocalErpSubbrand,
        HarmonizedSubbrand,
        GrossRevenue,
        Priority,
        Validated,
        MarketUnitName,
        UpdatedBy
    )
    VALUES (
        SellingSkuCode,
        modified.MaterialDescription, 
        modified.TranslatedMaterialDescription,
        modified.LocalErpSubbrand,
        @HarmonizedSubbrand,
        modified.GrossRevenue,
        modified.Priority,
        modified.Validated,
        @Market,
        @UpdatedBy
);


WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        SellingSkuCode AS SellingSkuCodez
    FROM
        OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
            SellingSkuCode                varchar(100),
            MaterialDescription           varchar(8000),
            TranslatedMaterialDescription varchar(8000),
            LocalErpSubbrand              varchar(8000),
            HarmonizedSubbrand            varchar(500),
            GrossRevenue                  varchar(100),
            Priority                      varchar(100),
            Validated                     varchar(100),
            MarketUnitName                varchar(100),
            UpdatedBy                     varchar(100)
        )
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        cte
        INNER JOIN ProductValidation B ON cte.SellingSkuCodez = B.SellingSkuCode
)
MERGE ProductValidation_Feedback original
USING cte2 modified ON (
    original.SellingSkuCode = modified.SellingSkuCode
    AND
    original.MarketUnitName = modified.MarketUnitName
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    original.SellingSkuCode                = modified.SellingSkuCode,
    original.MaterialDescription           = modified.MaterialDescription,
    original.TranslatedMaterialDescription = modified.TranslatedMaterialDescription,
    original.LocalErpSubbrand              = modified.LocalErpSubbrand,
    original.HarmonizedSubbrand            = @HarmonizedSubbrand,
    original.GrossRevenue                  = modified.GrossRevenue,
    original.Priority                      = modified.Priority,
    original.Validated                     = modified.Validated,
    original.MarketUnitName                = @Market,
    original.UpdatedBy                     = @UpdatedBy

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (
        SellingSkuCode,
        MaterialDescription,
        TranslatedMaterialDescription,
        LocalErpSubbrand,
        HarmonizedSubbrand,
        GrossRevenue,
        Priority,
        Validated,
        MarketUnitName,
        UpdatedBy
    )
    VALUES (
        SellingSkuCode,
        modified.MaterialDescription,
        modified.TranslatedMaterialDescription,
        modified.LocalErpSubbrand,
        @HarmonizedSubbrand,
        modified.GrossRevenue,
        modified.Priority,
        modified.Validated,
        @Market,
        @UpdatedBy
);
```

Took me forever just to get this working, as I was stuck on joining the CTEs.  Now it works, but trying to see if it can be improved from speed/performance angle.

Comment: 1. **Always** use `HOLDLOCK` with `MERGE`. 2. You should schema-qualify all of your object-names. 3. SQL Server (and most (all?) RDBMSs today really _don't like_ tables with lots of large `varchar` columns because it leads to off-table storage, so consider redesigning your DB if possible. 4. Are you sure about using `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` here? 5. Your `WHEN MATCHED` clauses should check for changes using `SELECT src.... EXCEPT SELECT tgt...` to avoid unnecessary writes. 6. Convention with `MERGE` is to name the two operand tables as `tgt` / `TARGET` and `src` / `SOURCE` respectively

Comment: Don’t use SELECT *, only select the columns you are actually going to use

Comment: Also, what is the point of cte2? I can only think you are using it to get modified.SellingSkuCode but as that has the same value as cte.SellingSkuCodez it doesn't seem to be adding anything

Comment: Hey @NickW, the incoming JSON data only contains SKUs and nothing else.  The purpose of CTE2 is to join the SKUs with the rest of their attributes (i.e. the full records that we intend to UPDATE/INSERT).

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: @drum using SQL Server 12.0.2000.8

Comment: @DBanks SQL Server 12.0 is 9 years old - you should update.